# WIN32 and UNIX don't change in CMake cross-compile

Tags: c, cmake, compilation, cross-platform, cross-compiling

I made a test CMakeLists.txt. I set system name and version before reading variables (although I didn't set the compiler):

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(test)

include_directories(.)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.10240.0)

add_executable(test test.c)

target_link_libraries(test)

message("cmake system name = ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME}")
message("cmake host name = ${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME}")
message("cmake system version = ${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}")
message("unix = ${UNIX}")
message("win32 = ${WIN32}")
```

Here is the output from "cmake ." on the terminal:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.4.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
cmake system name = Windows
cmake host name = Linux
cmake system version = 10.0.10240.0
unix = 1
win32 = 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/francisco/Documents
```

The CMake documentation says UNIX and WIN32 are set to the *target* OS. Here I set the target OS and yet they remain set to the host OS. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to write `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` after the first `project()` command is encountered by CMake. At the first `project` command the choices of compiler and target system are made and you cannot change the effects of this later. As you have seen you can overwrite the value of `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, but the only effect of doing this are that you and any external cmake logic that may be invoked (e.g. scripts executed when using `find_package`) see a value that is wrong (i.e. not matching the choice of compiler).

For setting this kind of information your `CMakeLists.txt` files are the wrong place. This kind of info belongs into a [toolchain file](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html) alongside your choice of compiler that actually produces binaries for the target platform:

toolchain-windows.cmake

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Windows)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 10.0.10240.0)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER <command/absolute path to executable to use as C compiler goes here>)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <command/absolute path to executable to use as C++ compiler goes here>)

...
```

Configure the project using something like

```
cmake --toolchain path/to/toolchain-windows.cmake -S path/to/source -B path/to/build/dir
```

**Note:** The default compiler on your linux almost certainly won't be able cross compile for windows targets.